# How do I stop white space at bottom of screen with WKWebView?

Tags: swift, wkwebview, swift5

Can anyone help me with removing the white space at the bottom of an iPhone that has a curved screen. For example the iPhone XS Max?

With the code below it leaves a blank white ugly bar at the bottom and I am stuck.

I have looked on here and cannot find anything to help.

```swift
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string:"https://google.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```

Expected to not have white bar at bottom and page to spread all the way to the bottom.

Comment: code is correct! change the url and check. i have checked with `let myURL = URL(string:"https://apple.com")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bottom constraint is currently pinned to the safe area. On the iPhone X, iPhone XS and iPhone XS Max the safe area doesn't extend to the bottom because of the home button indicator.

Try this:

```
webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

[image]